# problem with UiImageView.image = nil

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

**.h file**

```
  @interface AppViewController : UIViewController {
  ...
  UIImageView *imageViewArray[3][5];// not using any @property for this
  ...

 }
  ...
 #define FOR(j,q) for (int j = 0; j < q; j++)
```

**.m file**

```
  ViewDidLoad{
     FOR(i,5){
    FOR(j,3) 
    {
        image_names[0] = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",j]];
        imageViewArray[j][i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image_names[0]];
        CGRect newFrame ; 
        newFrame = CGRectMake(60+(j*130), 110+(150*i),130,136); 
        imageViewArray[j][i].frame = newFrame;
        [self.view addSubview:imageViewArray[j][i]];
      }
    }                   
}

 //clear the previous images and call a method to add new
 -(IBAction)Change{
      FOR(i,5)
        FOR(p,3) 
           imageViewArray[p][i].image = nil;

      [self ImageSwitch];
}


 -(void)ImageSwitch{

           FOR(i,5){
        FOR(j,3) 
        {   
           image_namesTmp[0] = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",j+3]];
           imageViewArray[j][i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image_namesTmp[0]];
           CGRect newFrame ; 
                 newFrame = CGRectMake(60+(j*130), 110+(150*i),130,136); 
              imageViewArray[j][i].frame = newFrame;
          [self.view addSubview:imageViewArray[j][i]];
                    }
               }
           }
```

when i press  the button for the first time it works fine(old images get replaced with new ones),but if i do it second time

```
        imageViewArray[p][i].image = nil;
```

this line wont work and all the previous images still remain there and new images are overlapping with the present ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ImageSwitch` method you are always creating new instances of `UIImageView`.

```
imageViewArray[j][i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image_namesTmp[0]];
```

At this point, there already is a reference to UIImageView stored in the variable. You are losing your reference to it and since you alloc/inited it, you will most probably also leak its memory. Moreover, you are adding new UIImageViews to the view hierarchy, but you are not removing the old ones.

Try something like this:

```
[imageViewArray[j][i] removeFromSuperview];
[imageViewArray[j][i] release];
imageViewArray[j][i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image_namesTmp[0]];
```

Comment: if i add this code to my ImageSwitch.the new images are being displayed for fraction and then they disappear

Answer (score 1):

Second time you set your images you don't need to recreate the `UIImageView` objects. Your `ImageSwitch` method is better declared as,

```
-(void)ImageSwitch{

    FOR(i,5){
        FOR(j,3) 
        {   
            imageViewArray[j][i].image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",j+3]];
        }
    }
}
```

Just changing the images will suffice and that's what you need to do.

Comment: so i dont have to call release rite??

Comment: this didn't do the magic yet :( i still get the overlap of images on previous ones!!!

Comment: Are you creating new image views elsewhere?

Comment: If that is the case and you've implemented `ImageSwitch` exactly as in my answer, it's difficult to see how they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You need an NSMutableArray of ImageViews. In your header declare the NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *_imageViewArray;
```

Then in your viewDidLoad method initialize the array and then populate it with your image views.

```
_imageViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i =0; i < imageNames; i++) {
   UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i];
   [_imageViewArray addObject:tempImageView];
   [tempImageView release];
 }
```

So thats the image view array populated, you may do it a different way but thats up to you.
To switch the views over what I would do is like so...

```
[self.view removeAllSubviews]; // gets rid of all previous subviews.
[self.view addSubview:[_imageViewArray objectAtIndex:3]];// could be any number. generate a random number if you want.
```

Thats all you would need to do. If you wanted to know which image view was being displauyed the maybe declare an instance of UIImageView in your header called _currentImageView and then you can remove just that image view instead of all subviews.
Hope this helped.